# Não entendo a ordem de execução de um código

Tags: java, lógica, variável-estática

```
public class Rope {
    static String result = "";
    {result += "c";}
    static
    {result += "u";}
    {result += "r";}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(Rope.result + " ");
        System.out.print(Rope.result + " ");
        new Rope();
        new Rope();
        System.out.print(Rope.result + " ");

    }
}
```

O resposta para essa questão é: u u ucrcr

Só não entendo porque no final imprime apenas o cr, não consigo encontrar uma lógica, pela minha lógica deveria ser: u u ucrucr. Porque esse último u é omitido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando a aplicação começa executar em algum momento ela inicializará os membros estáticos. É garantido que isto ocorre antes de qualquer instância classe ser inicializada. Então cria a variável `result` valendo um texto vazio. Em seguida adiciona a letra `u` nele. Este valor é impresso duas vezes. A parte estática é esta:

```
static {result += "u";}
```

Aí cria-se uma instância da classe. Neste momento é executado dois blocos que não são estáticos, são eles:

```
{result += "c";}
{result += "r";}
```

Então ao `u` já existe concatena `cr`. Agora `result` contém `ucr`

Em seguida cria outra instância que novamente concatena mais um `cr`.  Agora `result` contém `ucrcr`.

Manda imprimir isso e o resultado está correto. Não omite último `u` algum. Inverto a pergunta, porque acha que teria um `u` ali? Não vejo lógica nisso.

Fiz um teste de mesa para descobrir. E claro, sabendo como os blocos estáticos e de instância são executados. Mas dá para aprender como Java se comporta só fazendo o teste de mesa.

Provavelmente fizeram isto como pegadinha para ver se a pessoa entende como é executado mesmo com uma sintaxe pouco legível. Ou queriam saber se a pessoa entende como  o Java funciona, ou se ela consegue descobrir isso fazendo o teste de mesa. Isto é mais importante.

Assim seria mais fácil se a pessoa entender como o Java funciona:

```
public class Rope {
    static String result = "";
    static {result += "u";}
    {result += "c";}
    {result += "r";}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(Rope.result + " ");
        System.out.print(Rope.result + " ");
        new Rope();
        new Rope();
        System.out.print(Rope.result + " ");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ykmFbt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xqhvkwsv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/ExecutionOrder.java).

Comment: Agora entendi, meu vacilo foi pensar que ao criar new Rope(), eu estava adicionando novamente o u, mas ele não chama o bloco static, apenas o bloco com o cr. Foi um pouco de falta de atenção. Obrigado.